# Acquiring SSO token in mobile outlook client

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, office-js, outlook-addin, office-js-helpers

I´m having trouble to get SSO working in my javascript based addin for the mobile outlook app.

With the example here

https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-attachments-demo

And this documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#add-client-side-code

Its possible to get the SSO token in the Windows and Web Outlook client, as long as it doesnt open up the dialog for the OAuth way, which will result in an error inside the dialog after i selected my O365 account (on mobile too) with the following message

```
TypeError: The Object doesn't support property or method "displayDialogAsync"
```

On mobile client, the following APIs are not available

```
Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync
OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken
```

And the following API which is working on the mobile outlook app is just very limited in its scopes which is not useable for me

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync
```

So how can i optain a silent token for the current mailbox user in the mobile outlook app?

Answer (score 0):

Currently SSO is not a part of the Outlook Mobile. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Meanwhile you can try [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview)

Comment: When we try calling OfficeRuntime.Auth.getAccessToken( ) we get an error saying "OfficeRuntime is not defined" Is this still the case in August 2021 ?