# Outlook Add-in - SSO support on Outlook Mobile

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create an online meeting mobile add-in for Outlook, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/online-meeting). The add-in itself works fine, until I try and obtain an access token using SSO (calling Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync
or OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken). No exception is thrown, but the request to convert the meeting to an online meeting eventually times out with a generic error message.

I can obtain the Exchange Identity just fine (office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync). I have also tried calling the same javascript function from a button on Outlook Desktop and I receive an access token, so I believe I have SSO configured correctly in the manifest and the Azure AD app.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679420/acquiring-sso-token-in-mobile-outlook-client), posted a year ago, states that SSO was on mobile was not supported at this time. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we do not support SSO on Mobile platform. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.